# VBA For Each item in ... why does it not stop at the end

Tags: vba, for-loop

Hi struggling with some basic code ... could someone please explain this code, why does it shove 2 extra lines on the end ...

```
Sub main()
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim ifToSave As Variant
    
    Dim fileType(5) As String
        fileType(0) = "1"
        fileType(1) = "2"
        fileType(2) = "3"
        fileType(3) = "4"
        fileType(4) = "5"

    For Each item In fileType
        ifToSave = item & " - apple"
        Debug.Print item
        Debug.Print ifToSave
     Next item
End Sub
```

Outputs this

> ```
> 1
> 1 - apple
> 2
> 2 - apple
> 3
> 3 - apple
> 4
> 4 - apple
> 5
> 5 - apple
>
>  - apple
> ```

Where this doesnt

```
  For i = 1 To 5
    ifToSave = i & " - apple"
    Debug.Print i
    Debug.Print ifToSave
  Next i
```

Comment: `Dim fileType(5) As String` is an array containing SIX items. You didn't set anything to `fileType(5)`, but your loop is printing it. Hence the extra 2 rows. You were right to assign a value to `fileType(0)` (because VBA arrays are 0 based), but you probably only need `Dim fileType(4) As String`.

Comment: Also please don't attempt to circumvent the rules by adding extra text for no reason :)

Comment: change the declaration to Dim fileType(0 To 4) As String

Comment: You can set [Option Base 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-base-statement) however, this causes a lot of confusion, arrays by default always start at 0 in any programming language and you should consider that at all times. I just commented this if you ever come across that in a code, but I don't suggest to use it at all.

Comment: Many thanks - obvious now - sign of age I'm afraid, it'll happen to you all one day :(

Comment: "please don't attempt to circumvent the rules" - fair enough ... but maybe the rules are wrong! or just bad programming :)